# Installing curl-loader in linux machine

Tags: linux, curl

I downloaded curl-loader version 0.56 in linux machine. When I execute make command I got the below mentioned error. Could anyone please tell me how to fix it?

Also I have installed [rtmpdump](http://sourceforge.net/p/curl-loader/mailman/curl-loader-devel/thread/91277901223af332bf762a8470c17eae@andrei.myip.org/) and got the following error:

```
./lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o): In function `rtmp_disconnect':
curl_rtmp.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `RTMP_Close'
curl_rtmp.c:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `RTMP_Free'
./lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o): In function `rtmp_connect':
curl_rtmp.c:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `RTMP_Connect1'
./lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o): In function `rtmp_send':
curl_rtmp.c:(.text+0x141): undefined reference to `RTMP_Write'
./lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o): In function `rtmp_recv':
curl_rtmp.c:(.text+0x17a): undefined reference to `RTMP_Read'
./lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o): In function `rtmp_setup':
curl_rtmp.c:(.text+0x1da): undefined reference to `RTMP_Alloc'
curl_rtmp.c:(.text+0x1ef): undefined reference to `RTMP_Init'
curl_rtmp.c:(.text+0x1fc): undefined reference to `RTMP_SetBufferMS'
curl_rtmp.c:(.text+0x20f): undefined reference to `RTMP_SetupURL'
curl_rtmp.c:(.text+0x234): undefined reference to `RTMP_Free'
./lib/libcurl.a(curl_rtmp.o): In function `rtmp_do':
curl_rtmp.c:(.text+0x266): undefined reference to `RTMP_ConnectStream'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [curl-loader] Error 1
admin123@ubuntu-server:~/curl-loader-0.56$
```

Followed the steps mentioned [here](http://lost-and-found-narihiro.blogspot.com/2013/04/ubuntu-1204-64bit-install-curl-loader.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I added the option `--without-librtmp` in Makefile, I am able to compile successfully.

The errors I got are related to rtmp library. I have installed rtmpdump in my machine by executing the command `sudo apt-get install rtmpdump`, but still I got the same error during compilation.

I have followed the solution in the link `sourceforge.net/p/curl-loader/mailman/curl-loader-devel/thread/…` to fix the make issue. When I try to compile the curl loader without rtmp library, it got completed successfully.

Comment: Why? Give a reason, a textual explanation, too. Only a flag is not enough. We don't need wizardry, we want to understand things.

Comment: The errors i got are related to rtmp library. I have installed rtmpdump in my machine by executing the command "sudo apt-get install rtmpdump", but still i got the same error during compilation. I have followed the solution in the link http://sourceforge.net/p/curl-loader/mailman/curl-loader-devel/thread/91277901223af332bf762a8470c17eae@andrei.myip.org/  to fix the make issue. When i try to compile the curl loader without rtmp library, it got completed successfully.

Comment: O.k. Here is some upvote and formatting. Now you should yet accept the answer which solved your problem by clicking the pipe icon on the left. It is important, if you don't do that, then your question left unsolved.

Comment: i am not able to accept my own answer today. I am getting error message saying "You can accept your own answer tomorrow". I will accept it tomorrow. Thanks for the information Peter.

Comment: Yes, you are. You can't _upvote_, but accept is okay. Just click on the pipe.